# Как правильно установить php модуль ssh2?

Tags: php

Не могу третий день понять, как установить ssh2-модуль для php. Пробовал в php.ini указывать php_ssh2 и сам dll лежит в ext, но не находит. Может я что-то не так делаю. Есть ещё папка libssh2, с которой я не знаю что делать (качал отдельно от файла). Использую php 7.2, логов нет.[image: Использую php 7.2, логов нет]

Comment: разрядность модулей то совпадает? гляньте логи чего пишет. мб сам модуль не запускается, а может уже модуль зависимые библиотеки найти не может

Comment: @teran, логов нет по этому поводу

Comment: И да, разрядность совпадает

Comment: Скорее всего зависимою библиотеку не может найти и я не знаю куда указать пусть к библиотеке, или как ее установить правильно. Библиотека "libssh2"